# How does the retrieve operation of a JDBCOutboundInterface in IBM Integration Designer work?

Tags: integration, ibm-bpm, websphere-process-server

I have following issue with IBM Integration Designer (BPM Advanced 8.5.6):

I want to retrieve a row from a database table, thus I created a JDBCOutbound interface via wizard. The Designer automatically creates a Business Object Type as input for this operation, being built up of one string named "verb" and another generated BO which just has all the columns of my table as attributes. When I now try to assign something to the "verb" variable I only have the values "insert, update and delete" as possible values in the dropdown. But I actually want a Select. 
Does anybody know what to do in this case?

Thanks in advance!

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the verb is ignored, when you have a retrieve operation. All you have to pass is the BO with the field values you want to search for.